# Seg fault when printing string array line, works fine when printed character by character

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, printf, dynamic-arrays

I have this code:

```
char **data;
int start = 0;

data = malloc(all_names * sizeof(char*));

        fd=open(argv[1],O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRWXU);
        for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
            data[i] = malloc((MAX_SIZE+1)*sizeof(char));

            int end = atoi(positions[i]);
            lseek(fd,0,start);
            read(fd,data[i],(end-start));
            data[i][end - start] = 0; //line edited in after answer
            start = end;

        }

        qsort(data, all_names, sizeof(char*), strcmp);

        for(int i=0; i<all_names; ++i)
        {
            printf("%s\n", data[i]);
        }

        /*//print data array
        start = 0;
        for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
            int end = atoi(positions[i]);
            for(j=0;j<(end-start) ;j++){
                printf("%c",data[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }*/
```

What I get when running it is a seg fault when trying to print.

If I comment out `qsort` and the printing `for`, and comment in the *print data array* part, I get, as expected, all my entries in the order I inserted them in.

If I leave `qsort` out, but keep the for loop as my printing method, I still get a seg fault.

1.The strings in the data array come from a file so they re probably not null terminated. However, I am hesitant to add a null byte cause it **must not be there** when I write the sorted array back in the file.

2. **positions array contains the starting point of every entry, apart from the first one. Eg. if I insert "alpha one" and then "beta two", then positions[0] = 9.

Please tell me to further explain anything I haven't done a good job explaining. Thanks.

Edit: Entire code cause it turns out I can't locate the problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 50

int updateCounter(int pcounter, char *str){
int m,charcount = 0;
for(m=0; str[m]; m++) {
        charcount ++;
}
//charcount--;
printf("chars: %d \n", charcount);

pcounter = pcounter + charcount;
printf("pcounter = %d \n", pcounter);

return pcounter;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int option,i,j;
FILE *fptr;
char *name;
int dcounter,pcounter = 0;
int fd;
char **positions,**data;
int all_names=0; //keeps track of how many names are currently stored
int start = 0; //first byte of word to read in data.bin
char *filename = argv[2];

name=(char*)malloc((MAX_SIZE+1)*sizeof(char));

do{
    printf("MENU: \n 1.Insert \n 2.Delete \n 3.Search \n 4.Display \n");


    printf("Please choose 1-4\n");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    while(getchar() != '\n');

    //Insert
    if(option==1){

        printf("Insert name: ");
        fgets(name,MAX_SIZE,stdin);
        name[strcspn(name,"\n")]=0;

        fd=open(argv[1],O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND,S_IRWXU);
        write(fd,name,strlen(name));

        pcounter = updateCounter(pcounter, name);

        char passpos[5];
        sprintf(passpos,"%d",pcounter); //int to string
        fd=open(argv[2],O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND,S_IRWXU);
        write(fd,passpos,3);
        write(fd," ",1);

        all_names++;
        printf("all names: %d\n",all_names);

        positions = malloc(all_names * sizeof(char*));

        //create pos array
        fd=open(argv[2],O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRWXU);
        for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
            positions[i] = malloc((MAX_SIZE+1)*sizeof(char));
            for(j=0; ;j++){
                read(fd,&positions[i][j],1);
                if (positions[i][j] == ' ') {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //print pos array
        for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
            printf("%s\n", positions[i]);
        }

        //create data array
        data = malloc(all_names * sizeof(char*));

        fd=open(argv[1],O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRWXU);
        for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
            data[i] = malloc((MAX_SIZE+1)*sizeof(char));

            int end = atoi(positions[i]);
            lseek(fd,0,start);
            read(fd,data[i],(end-start));
            data[i][end - start] = 0;
            start = end;

        }

        qsort(data, all_names, sizeof(char*), strcmp);

        for(int i=0; i<all_names; ++i)
        {
            printf("%s\n", data[i]);
        }

        /*//print data array
        start = 0;
        for(i=0; i<all_names; i++){
            int end = atoi(positions[i]);
            for(j=0;j<(end-start) ;j++){
                printf("%c",data[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }*/

    }

}while(1);
```

}

Comment: Please show a [mcve], the problem as well as the input required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why do you alloc `MAX_SIZE+1` bytes, if you read `start` and `end` afterwards and can derive the correct length?

Comment: regarding: `data = malloc(all_names * sizeof(char*));`  1) strongly suggest calling `calloc()` instead so it will be easy to free() the memory afterward.  (note: the posted code fails to free the allocated memory, resulting in a massive memory leak.

Comment: regarding: `char *filename = argv[2];`  What is the expected input from the user?  2) never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the expected number of command line parameters

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code. Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: OT: regarding: `name=(char*)malloc((MAX_SIZE+1)*sizeof(char));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  casting just clutters the code.  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing the cast,  Suggest removing the `sizeof(char)` expression.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `char passpos[5];
            sprintf(passpos,"%d",pcounter); //int to string`  What happens when the `pcounter` exceeds 9999?

Comment: regarding: `write(fd,passpos,3);`  what happens when `pcounter` is greater than 999?

Comment: regarding: `if(option==1)
        {`   and `}
        }while(1); `   means the opening brace(s) are not properly linked to the closing braces(s).  This is a major logic error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that `MAX_SIZE` is the maximum size of a string.

But it should be `sizeof(char*)`.

The function `qsort` expects a parameter that indicates the size of each element.
The size of each element in a data type `char**` is the size of `char*`.

Here's an example, similar to your program, that's useful for quick testing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int all_names = argc;

    char** data = argv;

    qsort(data, all_names, sizeof(char*), strcmp);

    for(int i=0; i<all_names; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", data[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Regarding your updated code, after this line:

```
read(fd,data[i],(end-start));
```

You should null-terminate your string.

```
data[i][end - start] = 0;
```

I say this with the assumption that `end - start` does not account for a null-terminating character and that you're not storing null-terminated characters in the file you're reading from.

Regarding your additional update, if you don't want to write the null-terminator to the file, then just find the length of the string using `strlen` before writing it to the file. Your other option would be to write a wrapper for `qsort` that looks something like this.

```
int cmp_string_block(const void* a, const void* b) {
    return memcmp(a, b, MAX_SIZE);
}
```

And then pass that function to `qsort` instead of `strcmp`.

Comment: I no longer get a set fault, but for example, if I insert "beta two" and then "alpha one" into the array, what gets printed is "beta twoa". The problem is that I don't know if its the sorting's fault or something wrong with my printing, cause: printing a line never works, even before sorting. But printing it as character by character works before I sort.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<all_names; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", data[i]);
    }`

Comment: You are passing `sizeof(char*)` and not `sizeof(char)` right? If you are, you can ignore the compiler warning in that particular case.

Comment: I am yes. I can't understand why, leaving the sorting out, I have trouble printing like this `for(int i=0; i<all_names; ++i) { printf("%s\n", data[i]); }`. I know the array has been created correctly cause the printing char by char works as I say in my question.

Comment: And you're definitely using `char**` as a string array type? It's hard to say. You're putting all of the people looking at your code at a disadvantage to help you by not posting the entire code. If the code is too long to post, try reducing it to a smaller section of code that still has the problem.

Comment: I don't know how to do that cause the process is: store input by user into bin file, then transfer file data into array, sort array, print array. Is it possible that the strings stored to the array from the file are not null-terminated and I should post that part? Its too long and I m not sure what to leave out.

Comment: Yeah that's probably what the issue is. Allocate an extra byte for the null terminator and make sure you set it to zero. If you're still having issues after that, do your best to post the code so we can actually help you without asking so many questions!

Comment: Its a bit complicated. I revised the question completely, is that better?

Comment: @NeedHalp that's a bit better. See the updates on my answer and hopefully it helps.

Comment: Still getting the "beta twoa"

Comment: Then you could be calculating the array `positions` incorrectly. But I'm not really sure. You should really just post the entire code at this point.

Comment: Posted the whole thing then

Comment: @NeedHalp and even if your position values are being calculated correctly, it doesn't look like you're using them correctly in the for loop.

Comment: The for loop with the positions works fine though, but I can't use it after sorting cause then the positions are no longer accurate.

Comment: You don't really need the positions after reading the file. If you originally needed them when writing the file, when you could just use the string length to determine the positions all over again. If you want to keep the original order of the names in the, then this might be a reason to keep the position values. If this is the case, I would create a `struct` with the name string and the position value. You'll have to modify your call to `qsort`, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203195/discussion-between-needhalp-and-tay10r).